# What democratic systems exist that successfully tackle NIMBYism?

Tags: policy, city-planning, housing, citizen-activism

As [explained by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIMBY):

> NIMBY (an acronym for the phrase "Not In My Back Yard"), or Nimby (as
>   a word, instead of an acronym), is a pejorative characterization of
>   opposition by residents to a proposal for a new development because it
>   is close to them (or, in some cases, because the development involves
>   controversial or potentially dangerous technology) often with the
>   connotation that such residents believe that the developments are
>   needed in society but should be further away. The residents are often
>   called Nimbys and their state of mind is called Nimbyism.

Are there cities/countries which successfully deal with this problem, without violating basic principles of democracy? E.g. perhaps some countries delegate controversial projects to a vote by the state legislature, rather than allowing the city residents to vote directly?

Comment: just an example, hence not an answer: in Stuttgart there is strong opposition against the new underground high speed train station, so they let the whole region (Land) vote in a referendum in 2011. (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksabstimmung_zu_Stuttgart_21)

Comment: @Federico as far as I understand it didn't really resolve the issue and massive protests continued, slowing down the construction

Comment: I concede that a few discontents are still here, but I don't think that anything short of stopping the project would have satisfied them anyway. And my guess is that it would be the same with any NIMBY commitee. So now my question for you is: what do you define as "succesfully dealing with it"?

Comment: @Federico "successfully" = quickly, efficiently and without violating democracy. E.g. a city wants to build an airport, but locals are against it - a vote is then *immediately* scheduled for the whole city, and if the majority wants an airport - construction *immediately* begins. Obviously this could also include clauses about fair compensation, public hearings, etc, but nothing like the nightmares of modern airport expansions.

Comment: **Democratic** People's Republic of Korea

Comment: @JonathanReez Do you want to restrict freedom of speech and peaceful protest? Because most definitions of democracy would allow these, even against democratically legitimated decisions.

Comment: @Philipp no but protests shouldn't be able to prevent or slow down the construction of infrastructural objects, if they were properly voted on.

Comment: @K-C whatever it takes to quickly expand an airport or build a new prison

Comment: Basically, any democracy fits this in the specific case where majority supports the position except for small minority directly geographically affected - by virtue of punting the decision to wider locale (city to county, county to state, state to federal).

Comment: @user4012 then why do such projects always take so much time in democratic countries? E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_Heathrow_Airport

Comment: What would count as “successfully deal” with this problem in your eyes? Sure, every country has one or two examples of large projects that takes forever but stuff generally gets built. And city residents voting directly is the exception rather than the rule. More often than not when some large infrastructure project faces strong opposition it's through a grass-root movement or perhaps activists forcing the hands of the institutions. And they are mostly unsuccessful.

Comment: @Relaxed as an example, San Francisco is facing extremely high prices because the local residents don't want to allow high-rise apartment buildings near their properties. A "successful" solution would completely ignore the local residents and push everything through the state legislature at a very fast pace. Basically a country where it's impossible for NIMBYism to exist since only the opinion of large districts as a whole is taken into account - or perhaps where financial compensation is set-up in a way that leaves everyone happy.

Comment: @JonathanReez That's not even a clear example of NIMBYism for me, just competing interests or a different set of priorities. NIMBY is when everybody agrees something like a waste incineration plant needs to be built, just not where they live. And I don't know about San Francisco but most countries are pretty successful at building these things with local citizens seldom having much success in blocking or significantly delaying them. So it seems the only problem is that you just don't like democratic processes so much and prefer top-down decision-making.

Comment: @Relaxed well, my own country is NIMBY paradise - Czech Republic is unable to build numerous infrastructural projects for nearly three decades because the local people are in constant opposition. Perhaps I should instead ask why NIMBYs are successful in some countries and inexistent in others?

Comment: I'll try to provide a proper answer later, but Japan's land use laws at the national level are often hailed as anti-NIMBY.

Comment: @ohwilleke care to add your answer? :)

Comment: @Federico Seeing that the people of Stuttgart were more, not less, likely to support Stuttgart 21, compared to the Land overall, I fail to see how this is an example of NIMBYism ([see referendum results](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksabstimmung_zu_Stuttgart_21))

Comment: @JonathanReez Although NIMBYism is rampant in the UK (my local Lib Dems oppose all new housing), I'm not convinced that Heathrow expansion is a good example, seeing that many are opposed to any form of airport expansion, and many who live nowhere near Heathrow are opposed.

Comment: I'm reminded of someone living in a rural place in a forest in Sweden.  When interviewed about the prospect of a uranium mine that would open more or less underneath his home, he replied that he wasn't too happy about it, but that he was in favour of nuclear power, and therefore could not reasonably object to it.

Answer (score 8):

The only real solution to NIMBYism is to move power from local towards national levels.    Otherwise, you get... well... democracy.

People want their political system to improve their own lives, and to represent their own interests.   At a city or neighborhood level, increased development means higher density, more people, slower traffic, slower property appreciation, and the like.  Why would they be for that?

The solution, of course, to move the political decision-making to a level at which both the problems and solutions have to be considered together, and for which reasonable trade-offs can be made.

The more local the decision-making, the more likely NIMBY considerations will come to prevail.  Politics is all about trade-offs, and if the decisions are made where countervailing interests don't have to be considered, they won't be.

Comment: -1: Although everything in this answer may be true, it does not answer the question (what countries/cities deal the problem, and how). Also, answers based solely on "common sense" rhetoric are discouraged here and may attract downvotes and/or denials.

Comment: "increased development means … slower property appreciation" This seems counterintuitive, do you have a source for it?

Comment: The other solution widely touted is just the opposite. Move the authority to regulate development to a micro-level of just a few blocks in size at the sub-municipal level.

Comment: Link to Japan nationalizing zoning and getting success. https://www.sightline.org/2021/03/25/yes-other-countries-do-housing-better-case-1-japan/ Hyperlocal zoning discussed here https://www.manhattan-institute.org/hyperlocal-zoning-enabling-growth-block-and-street

Comment: Higher density is awesome, public transport is awesome. I couldn't walk to the supermarket when I lived in the suburbs. Well, I could, but it took an hour each way.

Answer (score 3):

After doing a lot of reading about this since 2017, the answer can be broken down into two groups:

1. Corrupt/poorly managed nations where builders can do whatever they want with zero oversight. One example would be [Dagestan in Russia](https://vakin.livejournal.com/863795.html) where home owners just go ahead and add new extensions to existing apartment buildings, no matter how ugly or unsafe this looks. Other examples include [the slums of India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharavi), [former slums of Hong Kong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kowloon_Walled_City), [favelas of Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favela) and numerous other developing nations.
2. Japan. It seems like the only developed nation where the construction process is relatively corruption free but also NIMBY-resistant is Japan. This [wonderful blog post](https://devonzuegel.com/post/north-american-vs-japanese-zoning) includes a great illustration of how it works there. The first image illustrates the zoning logic in Japan, the second is how it works in North America and in Europe to a certain extent:
   [image]
   [image]

The table above is sourced from the [Japanese Ministry of Land](https://www.mlit.go.jp/crd/city/plan/tochiriyou/pdf/reaf_e.pdf) which showcases their zoning logic:

[image]

This still means that there are areas in Japan that are exclusively reserved for single family homes but those are not dominating Japanese cities. Japanese real estate costs [remained relatively stable](https://data.oecd.org/price/housing-prices.htm#indicator-chart) since the 1980s bubble burst:

[image]

Since the year 2000, Japan's housing price index dropped from 138 to 110. Meanwhile in the US they've increased from 63 to 142. Its not apples-to-apples comparison as Japan's population is shrinking while America's is growing but overall Japan somehow managed to avoid the rapid increase in housing costs over the past two decades. Japan is also one of the [very few nations](https://nsokolsky.substack.com/p/are-housing-prices-worse-than-ever?s=r) in the OECD where the price to income ratio has *decreased* over the past 20 years:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of examples i can give from Turkey:

1. Gold Mine project in Erzincan
2. Thermal Power Plant projects in the city of Amasra, and Trakya region.
3. Third Airport to Istanbul

Most of these projects are still contested by the locals, but probably will be carried out. Most of the time the way to deal with locals is to promise them jobs in the projects. With high levels of unemployment, this becomes attractive especially to youth. In an ideal system if this doesn't balance out the impacts of the project in the community, we would expect the annulation of the project.
However most of the time, in a law dispute, private companies have a very strong lawyer team that works things out, mostly by convincing locals to accept a certain amount of money for their expenses. This almost never cover the expenses of the locals though.

---

If it is the state that proposes the project, depending on the national benefit of the project, we can observe an annulation to deportation of locals to some place else. The deportation almost always ends up in misery, because one doesn't really notice it in urban areas but in rural areas where you live *really* matters and it determines one's way of life, you loose your place, you loose your way of life. This has happened in the construction of the dams in the south-east of Turkey. Even some archaeological sites went under the water, but the dams created the necessary infrastructure in order to farm the land for later generations.
I honestly believe that proposing jobs or a privilaged access to jobs and improving overall infrastructure of the locals (schools, hospitals,etc) is a reasonable way to convince people, when, of course, the project doesn't involve any health consequence in the long run, as in the case of gold mine project in Erzincan or plantations.

Comment: In countries with a higher level of income, standard of living, and all that, you don’t lure people with promises about their standard of living anymore. Their standard of living is already so high, that they just don’t want anything that could change their view in their neighborhood.

Comment: I don't disagree with your final paragraph, but is that really a democratic *system*, or just a smart way to convince people?

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, for housing, the central government tells local authorities *how many* houses (at a minimum) they must grant permission for, but they can then decide *where* in their area those houses can be built. That seems to strike a reasonable balance between meeting national needs and allowing local democracy, although of course it’s not feasible for large one-off projects. And it’s only partially successful — the UK still doesn’t build enough houses.

Comment: It also doesn't do anything about more high profile Nimby incidents like Heathrow expansion or Dover customs check parks.

Comment: As far as I can tell its still super hard to upgrade housing density in the UK? I.e. if I buy a single family home in London, how hard is it to tear it down and build a 4-story apartment building instead? In a no-NIMBY system the answer is: zero days, you just do it and everyone who dislikes it are told to deal with it.

Comment: @JonathanReez that particular change might be quite difficult, but other density increases attract less trouble. Locally (zone 4, london) I've seen a 4 bed detatched turned into 3, 4bed terraced houses. A retirement home into a 12 residence apparment block and a rapid increase in 12-20 story apartment buildings along train lines heading into London. So it can and is happening. Although I imagine none of that comes with zero days permission. If nothing else someone needs to crunch infrastructure numbers for schools, GPs, parking and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In England and Wales, a central government agency, the [Planning Inspectorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_Inspectorate), adjudicates on so-called [Nationally Significant Infrastructure Projects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationally_significant_infrastructure_projects). The system was set up under the [Planning Act 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planning_Act_2008) for controversial projects that were deemed nationally important such as airports, major wind farms, and nuclear power stations, with the expansion of Heathrow Airport one reason for its creation (see the Wikipedia pages I link above for more details).

This removes planning decisions from local government, reduces consultation requirements, and attempts to speed up the process by imposing time limits. Initially it gave powers to an independent commission, but in 2011 an amendment gave central government more control.

It has arguably worked for some projects, such as the Thames Tideway sewer tunnel, although Heathrow Airport still isn't any bigger, and especially in early years very few scheme were even submitted (2 in the first year, one of which were rejected).

Comment: This seems like an example of a failure to fight NIMBYism? Only successful project is a tunnel that's pretty much out of sight, out of mind for the NIMBYs.